# Leer fichero formato CSV en Java

Tags: java, csv

Quisiera saber cómo tengo que proceder para leer una archivo en CSV con Java y saltarme una coma de separación entre cada campo. Leer cada espacio que se encuentra pero yo quiero que sea cada coma (,) ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

Éste es mi código:

```
class Pruebas {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String cadena = "MetroBikeShare_2016_Q3_trips.csv";
        String elemento=null;
        boolean seguir = true;
        Scanner entrada = null;

        try {
            entrada = new Scanner(new File(cadena));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnE) {
            System.out.println(fnE.getMessage());
            seguir = false;
        }
        if (seguir) {
            entrada.nextLine();
            while (entrada.hasNext()) {
                elemento=entrada.next();
                System.out.println(elemento);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Debes poner lo que has intentado. Tu pregunta ahora mismo no está clara ni indica que hayas investigado nada. Se puede encontrar en muchos sitios justo lo que estás pidiendo. Si encuentras problemas con algo en concreto entonces pon una pregunta clara con [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Probablemente lo que necesites es afinar tus google search skills, por ejemplo mira lo que me salio como respuesta en la primera busqueda: 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo un [archivo CSV](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV):

```
John,Doe,120 jefferson st.,Riverside, NJ, 08075
Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila, PA,09119
"John ""Da Man""",Repici,120 Jefferson St.,Riverside, NJ,08075
Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD, 91234
,Blankman,,SomeTown, SD, 00298
"Joan ""the bone"", Anne",Jet,"9th, at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
```

Este es un ejemplo de como leer el contenido del archivo CSV:

```
String csvFile = "archivo.csv";
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
//Se define separador ","
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                
        String[] datos = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        //Imprime datos.
       System.out.println(datos[0] + ", " + datos[1] + ", " + datos[2] + ", " + datos[3] + ", " + datos[4] + ", " + datos[5]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jorgesys hola :D Leí el enlace que compartes justamente estoy trabajando con un archivo csv como dice en el contenido del enlace pueden haber un campo como este `"ac, abs, moon"` sería recomendable usar obturador o palote `|` como símbolo delimitador?

Comment: hola @PedroÁvila , se puede usar como separador, solo recuerda la definición de un .CSV, "comma separated values", por eso el uso de "," y además porque actualmente puede ser abierto para visualizar en varios programas, si usas el "|", (pipe) tendría esa limitación, pero también puede ser un delimitador de datos.

Comment: este codigo fallara si el CSV posee escaped por ejemplo:  `comment01`,`"hola, como estas"` el codigo separa en `comment01` `"hola` `como estas"` (o tambien en el caso que el texto posee Break lines en el campo) en este caso recomiendo ver esta implementacion que cumple con RFC4180 [CsvParser.java](https://gist.github.com/ECartman/53296e8dcf768ae1120c8b618036bd33)

Answer (score 0):

Yo también me encontraba en esa duda, lo que hice fue implementar el método [Split en Java](http://javainutil.blogspot.mx/2013/04/java-manejo-de-cadenas-metodo.html).

Este es un ejemplo de como implementarlo, y así puedes leer linea por linea del archivo y con el `split` lo guardas en otro `array` o `arraylist` como cadenas depende como lo vayas a usar

```js
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
             line = rd.readLine();
            linea = line.split(",");//separador 
            activity.add(linea[2]);//registro de actividades
           
            }
        System.out.println(activity);//imprimimos
```

en este caso yo solo quiero guardar las actividades de mi registro, por eso las guardo en un `array`  usando `split` que busca dentro de mi archivo, le doy la posición en este caso lo toma desde la posiciones 0 y mis actividades están en la posición 2 y después las imprimo para confirmar que solo sean las actividades.
Y del separador depende como lo tengas tu en tu archivo o definido en tu proyecto puede ser por: (",") o (";") o (".") .