# JavaFx con COMBOBOX

Tags: java, csv, javafx

Muchísimas gracias de antemano pero tengo una consulta a ver si me podéis ayudar ya que lo que necesito es que el programa que estoy haciendo me lea un archivo CSV en el que el propio programa guarda datos y de ahí me saque solo el nombre y me lo muestre en el combobox y cuando selecciono el nombre del combobox me lo muestre en los textview muchísimas gracias.

por ahora e intentado esto.... pero igualmente no funciona y ya no se como hacer lo.

```html
 @FXML private void mostrarcombo() {
         /*BufferedReader br = null;
         ComboBox<proveedores>  combo = new ComboBox<proveedores>();
         try {
          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CsvFile2"));
          String line;
                
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] fields = line.split(FieldDelimiter, -1);
                   /* combo.getItems().addAll(proveedores2.toString().length(), proveedores2);
                    proveedores proveedor = new proveedores();
                    proveedor.nombrep.set(fields[0]);
                    for(int a = 0; a<fields.length;a++) {
                     combo.getItems().addAll(proveedores2);
                    }
                    
                    
                    //System.out.println(fields[0]);
                    
                }
         }catch(Exception e) {
          
         }*/
         //ComboBox<proveedores> cmb = new ComboBox<>(proveedores2);
         
         
         BufferedReader br ;
         try {
          br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("CsvFile2"));
          combo.setItems(proveedores2);
          proveedores2.add(posicionClienteEnTabla, null);
         }catch(Exception e) {
          
         }
         
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Aquí se te ayudará sin duda, pero es necesario que muestres lo que has intentado, dónde te está fallando y qué fallo estás teniendo. Como comprenderás, no podemos imaginarnos tu programa, ni mucho menos crearlo en tu lugar.

Comment: Ahi esta la cosa que no se como crear eso y no tengo nada creado aun.

Comment: Pues no podemos hacerlo por ti. Tendrás que leer algún tutorial, los hay muy buenos, y empezar a programar. Y cuando tengas un problema concreto entonces lo planteas aquí y con gusto se te ayudará.

Comment: Cómo sabes que no funciona? Te da algún error? Que estructura de csv estás tratando de leer? Podrías darnos un ejemplo?

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38085/leer-fichero-formato-csv-en-java