# ¿Cómo crear una base de datos online?

Tags: java, base-de-datos

tengo un programa el cual me sirve para mostrar los elementos de la tabla periódica, los muestra uno a uno mediante un JComboBox. Pero se vuelve un problema al tratar de conseguir los datos de cada uno de los elementos, ya que los tengo en varios archivos de texto, y al momento de editarlos es poco práctico. Quiero saber si es posible acomodar los datos en una especie de tabla tipo excel o alguna base de datos desde la cual pueda obtenerlos y editarlos de una manera más sencilla. Es un programa offline, asi que no necesito conección a internet. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Oscar bienvenido al sitio, te invito a que leas el siguiente link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que te podamos ayudar. 
Saludos

Comment: Podrias utilizar un archivo csv el cual puedes abrir y editar con excel. En esta url muestran como usarlo y leerlo en java https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38085/leer-fichero-formato-csv-en-java