# ¿Cómo puedo leer este fichero separado por comas en Java?

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Imagen del fichero .txt

Necesito leer y mostrar por pantalla este archivo txt, que contiene una lista de números separados por comas. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo desde Java?

Comment: La pregunta es parecida a la siguiente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38085/leer-fichero-formato-csv-en-java favor revisa su respuesta para ver si te es de utilidad

Answer (score 0):

Es buena práctica por lo general al preguntar en este tipo de espacios, tener al menos una idea o noción básica de la solución, y hacer preguntas mas específicas, no tan genericas.

Dicho esto, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Usar un **BufferedReader, FileReader** para leer el archivo.
- Recorrer cada línea del archivo eliminando las comas.
- Usar una lista para añadir la data limpia.
- Recorrer la lista limpia, imprimiendo dicha data.

Algo como:

```
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String[] data = null;
    List<String> cleanData = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ARCHIVO.txt"));
        String row = "";

        while((row = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            data = row.split(",");
            for(String value : data) {
                stringBuilder.append(value);
            }

            cleanData.add(stringBuilder.toString());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!cleanData.isEmpty()) {
        for (String row : cleanData) {
            System.out.println(row);
        }

    }

    if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

PD: Esto es una respuesta rápida, pero los pasos serían esos en general.